# Angular: Re-enable automatic change detection

Tags: angular

I took over development of an Angular app from a collegue that already had things configured. One of those things is `OnPush` change detection. It seems that all the components are configured to have it. I changed one of my component's change detection strategy to Default but it still wouldn't detect any changes unless I call detectChange().

Where in my application should I change to revert automatic change detection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different things. You have manual change detection, in which you have the application provide the `NoopNgZone` as zone. This will disable all change detection. If this is the case, all you need to do is remove the `ngZone: 'noop'` setting:

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule, { ngZone: 'noop' }) // remove noop
```

If this is not the case, then I suppose you mean the `OnPush` `ChangeDetectionStrategy`, defined in the `Component` decorator. This only works if all the parents of the child also have their strategy set to `Default`.

However, I strongly advice you to keep it on `OnPush`, this will make your application faster, easier to test, and predictable. You won't have to deal with 'expression was changed after check' errors (almost never). The component is checked when an `@Input` value changed, or when an event happened from within the component.

You are better of rewriting your code, perhaps by utilizing the `async` pipe, to reduce the usage of `.detectChanges()` and `.markForCheck()`

---

For instance if you want a clock, you can do it like this:

```
readonly clock$: Observable<Date> = interval(1000).pipe(  
  map(() => Date.now()),
  startWith(Date.now())
);
```

And in your template:

```
<div>{{ clock$ | async | date:'medium' }}</div>
```

This will update your template every second to the current time and date.

That's the beauty of the `async` pipe. You don't have to subscribe and unsubscribe. This is all handled in the pipe. Under the hood, the async pipe also calls the change detection for that component on every emit. By saying that, make sure you put this 'clock' in a dedicated component, with a small template. This way the change detection will only run for that clock element, so you don't have any performance issues with the local change detection being run every second

Comment: I see, how would I go about showing time for example that ticks per second? Is detectChanges() the only option I have?

Comment: You can use rxjs. Let me show you an example in the answer

Comment: This is great. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you mean the `OnPush` change detection strategy by "manual change detection". The strategy is inherited from parent components, i.e., you would need to change those in order to revert to the default change detection strategy.

However, before doing so: do you really need the default change detection strategy (thinking of performance, ..)? When in doubt: there is a [good read on change detection strategies](https://netbasal.com/a-comprehensive-guide-to-angular-onpush-change-detection-strategy-5bac493074a4).

Comment: You're right I meant OnPush, I already clarified that in my question. I understand now that the change detection strategy is also inherited from the parent. As far as your question about performance, I'm developing component where a lot of information is being changed like a clock that ticks per second for example. Do you still recommend I use detectChange to update my view?

Comment: I can't really give a definitive answer to your specific case, but in my experience, in almost all cases it made sense to stick to `OnPush` and rewrite/restructure code (e.g., by creating smaller dedicated components) to keep things as simple as possible.